# Trying to learn go and gin post route with json

Tags: go

So I am fairly new to Go and Gin, and I have followed this article:

https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/web-service-gin

But I get this error: [image: error message]

My code looks like this.

```
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.GET("/albums", getAlbums)
    router.POST("/albums", postAlbums)

    router.Run("localhost:8080")
}

func postAlbums(c *gin.Context) {
    var newAlbum Album
    if err := c.BindJSON(newAlbum); err != nil {
        return
    }

    albums = append(albums, newAlbum)
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusCreated, newAlbum)
}

type Album struct {
    ID     string  `json:"id"`
    Title  string  `json:"title"`
    Artist string  `json:"artist"`
    Price  float64 `json:"price"`
}
```

and my postman request looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "4",
    "title": "Test title",
    "artist": "Unknow artist",
    "price": 15.99
}
```

So this code will not work, but if I try to alter it to this:

```
func postAlbums(c *gin.Context) {
    var newAlbum Album
    data, err := c.GetRawData()

    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &newAlbum)

    albums = append(albums, newAlbum)
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusCreated, newAlbum)
}
```

It works just as I would like too! How come the first function do not work? When it does i the article? Sry if I have done something completly wrong, I am still new to Go and Gin in general

Comment: `c.BindJSON(&newAlbum)` (you missed the address operation `&x`)

Comment: Thank you! That explains so much. I am still getting used to the whole pointers and refferences think.